# QueryException in Connection.php line 647: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146

Tags: laravel

I am new to laravel. I actually had the table but I intended to delete it from its directory migration folder because it wasn't no longer usable. When I started the test, those error appeared. I had jumped into connection.php line 647 but I had got nothing to do there. Any idea?
This is somewhat the code that i found around the line.

```
 catch (Exception $e) {
        throw new QueryException(
            $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
        );
    }
```

Comment: You have to give us more details and show the code you wrote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For which file you deleted. Generally when you are deleted the database migration file , you as well also must be delete from database in **migrations** table in remove entry which you are deleted the migrate file.

**Example Below**

If your file name is 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php which is deleted then you have to  delete in  database table name **migrations** table record.
[image]